# How to insert Apple's Color Emoji in Keynote?

Tags: macos, special-characters, iwork-keynote

How can I insert Emoji into my Keynote presentation?

From Keynote's menu under *Edit » Special Characters*, I can see the Emoji characters and drag and drop them to Keynote. But in Keynote (5.3) they become invisible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this is not possible.

Apple's Color Emojis are quite new in the way they are rendered, and applications may have to add specific support for them. Chances are you'll have to wait for a Keynote / iWork update in order to be able to use them.

See this blog entry for a few examples of what is already possible with Emoji: [Abusing Emoji in iOS and Your Mac](http://zachholman.com/posts/abusing-emoji/)

Answer (score 6):

This is now possible. You can add it by pressing `control-cmd-space` in a text box. This will open up the alternative keyboard with a list of emojis and symbols to choose from.

See here:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH24355?locale=en_US